# vb.net post image file to php return 0

Tags: c#, php, vb.net

This is the function to make the post

```
Public Function sendHttpRequest(url As String, values As NameValueCollection, Optional files As NameValueCollection = Nothing) As String
    Dim boundary As String = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x")

    Dim boundaryBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((Convert.ToString(vbCr & vbLf & "--") & boundary) + vbCr & vbLf)

    Dim trailer As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((Convert.ToString(vbCr & vbLf & "--") & boundary) + "--" & vbCr & vbLf)

    Dim boundaryBytesF As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((Convert.ToString("--") & boundary) + vbCr & vbLf)

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    request.ContentType = Convert.ToString("multipart/form-data; boundary=") & boundary
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.KeepAlive = True
    request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()

    For Each key As String In values.Keys

        Dim cntDisp = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""{0}"";" & vbCr & vbLf & vbCr & vbLf & "{1}"
        Dim formItemBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format(cntDisp, key, values(key)))
        requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length)
        requestStream.Write(formItemBytes, 0, formItemBytes.Length)
    Next

    If files IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each key As String In files.Keys
            If File.Exists(files(key)) Then
                Dim bytesRead As Integer = 0
                Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(2047) {}
                Dim cnt As String = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""{0}""; filename=""{1}""" & vbCr & vbLf
                Dim cntype As String = "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCr & vbLf & vbCr & vbLf
                Dim formItemBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format(cnt & cntype, key, files(key)))
                requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length)
                requestStream.Write(formItemBytes, 0, formItemBytes.Length)

                Using fileStream As New FileStream(files(key), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                    While (bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) <> 0

                        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    End While

                    fileStream.Close()
                End Using
            End If
        Next
    End If


    requestStream.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length)
    requestStream.Close()

    Dim reader As New StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())


    res = reader.ReadToEnd()

    Return res

End Function
```

I call it by

```
 Dim Path As String = "C:\dir\temp\"
    Dim fileLocation As String = Path + "FacePictureL.Jpeg"
    Dim fileLocation2 As String = Path + "LH1.Jpeg"
    Dim values As New NameValueCollection()
    Dim files As New NameValueCollection()
    values.Add("load", "OnPost")
    values.Add("value2", "value2")
    files.Add("FacePictureL", fileLocation)
    files.Add("LH1", fileLocation2)
    Dim sendData As New DataUpload()
    Dim response = sendData.sendHttpRequest("http://127.0.0.1/php/test/index.php", values, files)
    MsgBox(response)
    TextBox1.Text = response
```

on my php file i got a simple var_dump($_POST) and var_dump($_Files)

the post made well and recive the data, the images size is always 0 i try to change Content-Type but same result, so im stucked in here, Could you give me any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Why have added the C# tag?

Comment: The function was on c# i converted to vb, 
Assuming that the problem could be a conversion error and someone could guide me. regards

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer to this, after a few days of errors and research(before i made this post than only give a negative reputation, just remember... people like me in here  are just trying to learn and get some advanced help) this is the updated code to make a post with files in VB, using the actual call, I'm sure it'll help somebody else.

```
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Public Class DataUpload
Dim res As String
Public Function sendHttpRequest(url As String, values As 
NameValueCollection, Optional files As NameValueCollection = Nothing) As 
String
    Dim boundary As String = "----------------------------" + 
  DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x")
    Dim boundaryBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((Convert.ToString(vbCr & vbLf & "--") & boundary) + vbCr & vbLf)
    Dim trailer As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((Convert.ToString(vbCr & vbLf & "--") & boundary) + "--" & vbCr & vbLf)
    Dim boundaryBytesF As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((Convert.ToString("--") & boundary) + vbCr & vbLf)
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    request.ContentType = Convert.ToString("multipart/form-data; boundary=") & boundary
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.KeepAlive = True
    request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()

    For Each key As String In values.Keys
        Dim cntDisp = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""{0}"";" & vbCr & vbLf & vbCr & vbLf & "{1}"
        Dim formItemBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format(cntDisp, key, values(key)))
        requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length)
        requestStream.Write(formItemBytes, 0, formItemBytes.Length)
    Next
    Dim count = 0
    If files IsNot Nothing Then

        For Each key As String In files.Keys
            If File.Exists(files(key)) Then
                Dim bytesRead As Integer = 0
                Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(2048) {}
                Dim cnt As String = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""{0}""; filename=""{1}""" & vbCr & vbLf
                Dim cntype As String = "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCr & vbLf & vbCr & vbLf
                Dim formItemBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format(cnt & cntype, key, files(key)))
                requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length)

                requestStream.Write(formItemBytes, 0, formItemBytes.Length)

                Using fileStream As New FileStream(files(key), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                    While (BytesDataHelper(bytesRead, fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))) <> 0
                        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    End While
                End Using
            End If
        Next
    End If
    requestStream.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length)
    requestStream.Close()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    res = reader.ReadToEnd()
    Return res

End Function
Private Shared Function BytesDataHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, ByVal value As T) As T
    target = value
    Return value
End Function
 End Class
```